# How to order a dataframe column with integer like strings?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
<year joined>, <win streak>, <points>
2012           0-10 days     xxx
2013           0-10 days     xxx
2014           0-10 days     xxx
2012           1-2 years     xxx
2013           1-2 years     xxx
2014           1-2 years     xxx
2012           11-50 days    xxx
2013           11-50 days    xxx
2014           11-50 days    xxx
...
```

The issue is that the "win streak" column is ordered incorrectly because sorting by string makes "1-2 years" before "11-50 days".

What would be an affective way to order this dataframe so that year joined is still in order from 2012-2014, but that the win-streak groups are ordered in ascending order, even though they are brackets, and cannot be represented as true integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate fake data

```
z = as.factor(sample(c("0-10 Days", "11-50 Days", "1-2 Years"), 20, replace = TRUE))
z 
   [1] 0-10 Days  0-10 Days  11-50 Days 0-10 Days  0-10 Days  11-50 Days 11-50 Days 1-2 Years 
   [9] 11-50 Days 1-2 Years  0-10 Days  11-50 Days 11-50 Days 0-10 Days  1-2 Years  11-50 Days
   [17] 1-2 Years  1-2 Years  0-10 Days  0-10 Days
```

Define levels

```
levels(z) = c("0-10 Days", "11-50 Days", "1-2 Years")
sort(z)
   [1] 0-10 Days  0-10 Days  0-10 Days  0-10 Days  0-10 Days  0-10 Days  0-10 Days  0-10 Days 
   [9] 11-50 Days 11-50 Days 11-50 Days 11-50 Days 11-50 Days 11-50 Days 11-50 Days 1-2 Years 
   [17] 1-2 Years  1-2 Years  1-2 Years  1-2 Years 
   Levels: 0-10 Days 11-50 Days 1-2 Years
```

If you want to keep track of time, you can use `POSIXlt` class instead.